# How to force build system to ignore resource files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working with Android Studio 2.2. If I have resources (XML files, for example) that have errors in them, when I try to build these errors bring the entire build to a screeching halt, *even if I am not referencing them from my Activity.* I don't want to delete the files from their directories because I will *eventually* fix them, but they are not the priority at the moment. How in the world can I just "turn them off" for now, or at least tell the build system to ignore them? I tried doing the "keep.xml" tools:discard trick by adding their paths, but this doesn't do anything when compiling a debug target. The only way I can get the project to build is by either deleting the files out of the resources or moving them. This seems like overkill.

Comment: You can comment your resource files and later you can revisit.

Answer (score 0):

`lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}`

Adding this in your app gradle file will force it complete the build even with errors in it. Or, you can simply comment those files.